# matplotlib error : MatplotlibDeprecationWarning

Tags: pip, python-2.7, matplotlib

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py:680:    
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The is_string_like function was deprecated in version 2.1.  
  not cbook.is_string_like(colors[0]):
```

Now it's showing this error.

> from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/fontconfig_pattern.py", line 28, in  from backports.functools_lru_cache import lru_cache ImportError: No module named functools_lru_cache

Comment: So, update your matplotilb version?  It's in your local library - `pip3 install --upgrade --user matplotlib` should fix that.

Comment: now its showing this error.      from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "/home/rishabh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/fontconfig_pattern.py", line 28, in <module>
    from backports.functools_lru_cache import lru_cache
ImportError: No module named functools_lru_cache

Answer (score 2):

You have a MatplotlibDeprecationWarning when using the version of Matplotlib that was installed by pip. Install Matplotlib from the default Ubuntu repositories instead. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python2.7 python-matplotlib # 18.04 and earlier 
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/
```

Run the following commands in python:

```
matplotlib.get_configdir()  
matplotlib.get_cachedir()
```

Remove the matplotlib packages in the output paths of these commands. If there aren't any matplotlib packages in the output paths of these commands continue on to the next step.

Remove the matplotlib files in the .local folder.

```
mv /home/rishabh/.local/lib/python2.7/matplotlib* /home/rishabh/tmp
```

Type `python` to start the Python interpreter and then after the prompt type:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

You might also like to try running the plots inline in Spyder Python IDE.

```
sudo apt install python2.7 ipython python-matplotlib spyder # in Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier
```

After the ipython prompt in the IPython console copy/paste the below code and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to run it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
x, y = [-1, 12], [1, 4]  
plt.plot(x, y, marker = 'o')
```

[image]

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import defaultParams, validate_backend, cycler
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 29, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/fontconfig_pattern.py", line 32
    from backports.functools_lru_cache import lru_cache
ImportError: No module named functools_lru_cache